# Why did apt install dos2unix restart nginx?

Tags: nginx, apt

```
# apt install dos2unix
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dos2unix
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 33 not upgraded.
Need to get 418 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,540 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/universe amd64 dos2unix amd64 7.4.3-1 [418 kB]
Fetched 418 kB in 1s (754 kB/s)   
Selecting previously unselected package dos2unix.
(Reading database ... 113205 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dos2unix_7.4.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dos2unix (7.4.3-1) ...
Setting up dos2unix (7.4.3-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-2) ...
Scanning processes...                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Scanning candidates...                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Scanning processor microcode...                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Scanning linux images...                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

The processor microcode seems to be up-to-date.

Restarting services...
 /etc/needrestart/restart.d/systemd-manager
 systemctl restart amplify-agent.service irqbalance.service multipathd.service nginx.service packagekit.service php8.1-fpm.service polkit.service postfix@-.service rsyslog.service smartmontools.service ssh.service systemd-journald.service systemd-networkd.service systemd-resolved.service systemd-timesyncd.service systemd-udevd.service udisks2.service upower.service uuidd.service
Service restarts being deferred:
 systemctl restart ModemManager.service
 /etc/needrestart/restart.d/dbus.service
 systemctl restart networkd-dispatcher.service
 systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
 systemctl restart unattended-upgrades.service

No containers need to be restarted.

User sessions running outdated binaries:
 root @ session #80: bash[482511,541310,560013,701311,1038016], tmux: server[701357]
 root @ user manager service: systemd[1894]
```

My website went down for a split second while nginx was being restarted. Why did I not get any warnings about this? How do I prevent nginx from being restarted next time?

Comment: It is unlikely that the installation of dos2unix required services to restart.  Possibly  there were restarts pending  (due to for example unattended-upgrades ) and running apt manually, in interactive mode, triggered those. - Adjusting the [`needrestart`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man1/needrestart.1.html) mode to `(l)ist only`  and you should only see notifications about services needing restarts